# Ruby on rails authentication guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, system

Does anyone know of a good guide on building your own authentication system in ruby on rails?
I want to roll my own system to use with my community im building :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with [Warden](http://github.com/hassox/warden) - it'll handle the very basics of sessions for you, and give you a good foundation to build your logic on top of. The [Rails Warden](http://github.com/hassox/rails_warden) plugin is a rather small library that helps integrate it into Rails. Both of these projects are fairly mature and well-constructed yet still under active development - they're good choices all around.

You should be aware of [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), another authentication framework (like Authlogic or Restful Authentication) that is based on Warden. It may not be a good fit for your project (it wasn't for mine), but looking through the source might give you a few ideas on how best to use Warden.

The other thing I'll note is that, in terms of hashing passwords, you should absolutely use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: Devise seem to be created by the same guy who made Warden? is this right, I like Warden. But warden must go through this "Rack"? And what is this rack? if you could explain realy simple. Is it good? should i use it?

Comment: Warden and Devise share some developers, yes.

Rack is an interface between Ruby web frameworks and the servers they run on. Rails is built on top of Rack, so you're already using it. And, if you use Warden and Rails Warden, you don't have to worry about interacting with Rack directly - they'll take care of it for you.

There's a video explaining more about Rack here, if you're curious, but it's probably not something you need to worry about:

http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/06/05/episode-14-rack-metal

Answer (score 4):

michael hartl has a good book coming out soon and the first 8 chapters are available in pdf format for free here: http://www.railstutorial.org/ - they cover the entire process of creating a very solid rspec-driven authentication system - can't recommend it highly enough

Answer (score 2):

Well, it came out a while after you asked your question but the best answer if you're keen to build your own authentication system rather than use something like Devise would probably have to be [Ryan Bates' Authentication from Scratch Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch).

Comment: After reading that railscast I would also check out this one: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 1):

Since authentication is a common problem that has been solved many times already, I would start by investigating the solutions already out there.

For example, have a look at [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) which provides a good foundation for authentication in Rails.  Even if you'd rather roll your own system, playing around with Restful Authentication and understanding how it works should give you a good understanding of the components needed when you start building your own system.

Comment: i've tried both Restful Authentication and Authlogic and i don't think they fit me. thats why i want to roll my own

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of dissecting one of these solutions to understand how they work under the hood. Not only is it a good code-reading exercise, but once you've understood one of these systems it will be fairly easy to build your own solution, borrowing the ideas you like and changing the stuff you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

http://www.aidanf.net/rails_user_authentication_tutorial

The author goes, step by step, through an entire authentication framework, with suggestions on further improvements.  Even tests are discussed.

Comment: That article is almost four years old and doesn't conform to current best practices.  I'd avoid it and look for more up-to-date resources.

Comment: Really? could you maybe tell me where to look for "best-practice" info?  I've been looking for a good place to find that kind of info.  I had no idea the article was breaking conventions.

Comment: @G. Martin: The guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.com/ are great for reading up on the recommended ways of doing things nowadays. For example, the article you mentioned doesn't use RESTful routing. And `start_form_tag` and `end_form_tag` which are used for form generation in the article were deprecated in Rails 1.2 and removed in Rails 2.0 -- nowadays `form_for` or `form_tag` should be used.

Comment: @Par Wieslander  Ok.  I've used these before, and they can be pretty helpful.  However, they oftentimes feel a little impersonal.  Out of curiosity, are thos issues you mentioned the only things wrong with the guide I linked to?  I guess I'm wondering if there are any deeper problems with it.  I mean you could easily change the form routing stuff and the ideas the article presents would still be good right?

Comment: @G. Martin: I haven't checked all the details in the article, but yes, the overall ideas seem ok. So as long as you're aware of current Rails idioms and can adapt the deprecated parts to modern best practices I guess the article could still be somewhat useful. But for people still learning the basics it'll probably hurt more than it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ritchie... Devise has some very nice features but it doesn't play nice with others. For many use-cases, the way it hijacks the routing can make your job more difficult. In many situations you may be better off rolling your own.

Devise has caused circular references in my Rails asset pipeline, and the settings in the initializer as installed (in the latest version as of yesterday) conflicted with the defaults in the migration it generated.

I have built enterprise-level authentication systems, including email verification, password recovery, etc. And none of it required the routing shenanigans that Devise uses. If you really need all the features, it may be for you. But there are lots of reasons to not use it, too.